# Emailing from monodevelop .vs. VS2013

Tags: mono

I am attempting to email a small report once a larger process is done running.  The email code runs fine under windows 8.1 from VS2013, however when i move the code over to mono under Ubuntu(13.10) it gives the error --

```
ERROR 535 5.7.8 Error: Authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
```

-- What's puzzling to me is that if there is an Authentication failure under ubuntu/linux shouldn't the same Authentication failure be occurring under windows 8.1.   The email server is one which my company runs(not gmail.com/live.com/etc).  Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 

using System.Net.Mail; 
using System.Net; 
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates; 
using System.Net.Security; 

using S22.Imap; 
using S22; 

namespace testing_email { 
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.XXXXXX.com"); 

            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network; 
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false; 
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myreportuser@XXXXX.com", "password"); 
            client.Port = 25; 
            client.EnableSsl = true; 

            MailMessage mailit = new MailMessage(); 
            mailit.Body = "Body body body"; 
            mailit.Subject = "Testing Subject"; 
            mailit.IsBodyHtml = true; 
            mailit.From = new MailAddress("myreportuser@XXXXXX.com"); 
            mailit.To.Add("l.send.it@XXXXX.com"); 

            try {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; }; 

                client.Send(mailit); 
                Console.WriteLine("Message sent"); 
                Console.ReadLine(); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR " + ex.Message); 
                Console.ReadLine(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```